# Is it possible to use a group as one of the layers in a clipping group?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, clipping-mask

To make it perfectly clear - there are two types of layers in a clipping group

1. One layer which determines the boundaries of the group
2. One or more layers above `1.` which "pour into" the boudaries set by `1.`

I know I can use a group as `1.`, but is it possible to use a group as one of the `2.` layers?

I can use Smart Objects instead, but that way I can't see the rest of the image while editing the contents of the Smart Objects. A group would really be perfect, but the `Create Clipping Mask` option is not available on groups. That would answer my question, but I am also 99% sure that I've seen the downward pointing clipping mask icon on a group before.

Comment: You can't clip a group to a layer below, however you can apply a layer mask (either vector or raster) to a group.  [See example](https://imgur.com/a/dFIiwSo). Is that any use to you?

Comment: I think a simple screenshot of what you have and what you want would explain the question much better.